# Flex to JavaScript library/API

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

**Flex to JavaScript library/API**

I am looking for a "small" lib for exposing JavaScript objects within Flex/AS3.  I have looked at Adobe's FABridge, but that seemed to me to be more of JavaScript to Flex.  Are there any good examples of Flex using JavaScript objects with the FABridge?
...or some other Flex-JavaScript library more aligned in that direction that others know of / have used?

The only other one that I have looked at is the JSInterface ... but it is documented in Russian :-( ...

gsb

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking to do but if it's just simple communication between Flex and Javascript you can use the ExternalInterface class to do this. It allows a Flex app to invoke Javascript methods defined in the HTML wrapper and also allows Javascript to invoke methods in the Flex app that you expose via ExternalInterface.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 3):

i finished translation of [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jsinterface/wiki/help_english), [Presentation](http://actualwave.com/lab/pack/JSInterface_presentation_en.swf) and [ASDoc](http://jsinterface.googlecode.com/files/ASDoc_english.zip) to English. :)
You are welcome